# How to mass mail?

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a browser based gaming server, and it wasn't properly configured. In three days 420 people joined and all left because of mysql crashing and slow load time.

I upgraded the mysql and configured the server to run on low memory. Now It's super fast and crash proof. However all the players are already gone.

Good news is that I have a database full of 420 emails. I could tell them to come back and reward them. 
Can anyone show me an example of a php-mysql mass email script?

Comment: The paranoid person in me says to email only 10% of them.  If it goes well, email another 20%, ...  That way if you are wrong about being able to handle it, you only annoy a few people and you have a chance to fix it and try again with some others.

Answer (score 2):

you will have to iterate through a function that runs the same mailer against select all user emails...

i mean truth be told you will be lucky if an ISP doenst flag you down or if your hosting provider doesnt throttle you.

i would actually recommend doing this slower than faster. try doing one every minut so within a 6 hour cycle they all get rolled out.

you can use a pause in a script or run a persistant cron job.

Answer (score 1):

### Both of these solutions will keep you from getting blacklisted for a few pennies a month

#### Set up a mailchimp account for this few emails it should be free:

http://mailchimp.com/pricing/free/

import your mailing list into mailchimp and then split the users into multi campaigns and send mailers out to one of the campaigns track success and then adjust and start one of the other campaigns.

OR

#### use sendgrid's SMTP service.

http://sendgrid.com/pricing.html

using sendgrid you just configure your mailing script to connect via smtp (PHP Mailer can do this easy). $0.10 per thousand emails sent...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have trouble doing so on an offshore VPS those this are practically mail bombs.
Just use the mail() command in php.